# how to find the signed normal

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, self-learning

$$\gamma (t)= (R\cos (t/R), R\sin (t/R))$$
$$\dot {\gamma (t)}=(-\sin (t/R), \cos (t/R))$$
$$n_s= (-\cos (t/R), -\sin (t/R))$$

where $n_s$ is the signed normal.

the instructor has found the $n_s$. but i didnt know how to find $n_s$.

please can someone show me how to find it?  thank you

---

the signed normaol curve is obtained by rotating $t$ by 90 in the ccw direction

also i know that $$ \ddot {\gamma}=\kappa_s n_s$$

Comment: Do you know the definition of $n_s$? Could you please state this definition on your question?

Comment: yeap i added what i know on the question @Tomás

Comment: Goog, very good. Now let me ask you another thing. Do you know how to rotate a vector by a angle of $90$ degree?

Comment: nope. maybe $n.n_s=0$ isnt it? @Tomás

Comment: @B11b Try to rotate $(4,3)$ counterclockwise by 90 degree.  What are the coordinates of the rotated vector?  Now rotate an arbitrary vector $(a,b)$.  What are it's coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

First we note that the curve $\gamma(t)$ is parametrized by arc length, i.e., $\|\gamma'(t)\|=1$. This is important, because the usual definition for the tangent vector and the normal vector makes use of this fact.

Now, as you have said on the comments, $n_s$ is $\gamma'$ rotated by a angle of $90$ degrees. This implies that $$\langle \gamma'(t),n_s(t)\rangle=0,\ \forall\ t\tag{1}$$

For each $t$ the above equation has two solutions and we choose the solutions in such a way that $n_s$ is continuous. I suggest you to draw a graphic and see what is going on.
It is a exercise of Linear Algebra show that $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 \\
        1 & 0  \\
               \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        -1 & 0  \\
               \end{pmatrix}
$$

are the only two matrices of rotation by a angle og 90 degree. The first one conrresponds to a rotation of $\pi/2$ and the second one $-\pi/2$. The usual definition consists in choosing the first matrix to apply the rotation. This implies that $$n_s(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 \\
        1 & 0  \\
               \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
        -\sin\left({t/R}\right) \\
         \cos{\left(t/R\right)}
               \end{pmatrix}$$